# non-relational datastore design in scriptDB

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to working with non-relational datastores like scriptDB.  What would be the advantage of nesting your data in the objects to be stored?  Form the scriptDB  tutorial...
Why this,

```
{type: "employee",
  employee_id: 1,
  name: {first: "Fatima", initial: "S", last: "Pauli"},
```

And not this,

```
{type: "employee",
  employee_id: 1,
  first: "Fatima", 
  initial: "S", 
  last: "Pauli",
```

It seems a non-nested structure would be simpler, smaller and easier to access.  What am I missing???

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything - it is just a sample that illustrates the capabilities not the best practices at schema design for an object store.

Couple of things to keep in mind.

1. In the example above - since we are just querying by employee_id, the fact that name is a complex object doesn't affect querying at all. So we might as well a nested object there that we can add more attributes to at a later point and have it self contained.
2. Size should not matter here too much (maybe by few bytes an object). Think about how much data in an object and rather than its structure or small differences in property name.
3. You are ultimately storing objects - so you want to ensure that the object that you retrieve is easy to work with dot notation.

So, you'll have to see what makes sense in your code based on how the object is queried for and what its natural shape looks like.

Working with a document/object store does take a slight change in thinking - principles of normalization don't really apply the same. If you still prefer to work with SQL - Apps Script does have a [JDBC connector](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc) and recently [added support](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/11/get-started-at-no-cost-with-faster.html) for [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#accessing_google_cloud_sql_databases)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my query.  Have you come across any resources online/books that deal with best practices at schema design for an object store?  I am interested in exploring this topic further.

Comment: Sorry, nothing specific that I know about enough to recommend. Try looking at other NoSQL stores like MongoDB and CouchDB.